# mediaelement.js: Seeking to a specific time not possible in Firefox when not completely preloaded

Tags: mediaelement.js, preload, seek

I have the problem, that I can not seek an audio file (mp3) to a specific position if the file is not completely preloaded when using Firefox (10.0.2) (the position I want to jump is already preloaded), in Safari this works flawless.

Is this normal or do I have to change something on the server side or a bug of mediaelement.js? If I use jPlayer instead of mediaelement.js, it also works on Firefox (check it out here: http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-01/?theme=0)

But I’d prefer mediaelement.js because it has HTML5 syntax even if javascript is disabled. Thanks in advance!

Regards
Bernhard

Answer (score 2):

In a quick view, it seems that the JPlayer example you've posted provides both M4A and OGG audio files, not MP3. Providing an OGG source means that Firefox will use its native HTML5 capabilities. And the HTML5  specification includes progressive download and random jumping in the media file (if the webserver has the appropiate module, which is more or less a built-in feature in Apache and IIS, I think).

However, you want to use MP3, which is NOT natively supported by Firefox, which means that MediaElementJS will fallback to the Flash solution. And their plugin does not allow progressive download unless you're using RTMP protocol instead of HTTP. This, in turn, implies you need Flash Media Server or any alternative providing RTMP:

http://blog.denivip.ru/index.php/2011/02/flash-media-server-and-its-alternatives/?lang=en

And, when you have that, you need to not forgive to prepend "mp3:" to the filename in the URL. See my own question here some time ago, and how I finally solve it:

[Replacing media source (http with rtmp) in MediaElementsJS based on browser capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113633/replacing-media-source-http-with-rtmp-in-mediaelementsjs-based-on-browser-capa)

Hope this helps.